# Existing flow layout for variable width uicollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, variable-width

Is there any existing flow layout which can support a collection view which the user can scroll a collection of images in a horizontal direction but have the images have variable width and same height?  I have one sort of working but it sometimes randomly spaces the images.  Thanks.

Comment: When I touch the collection view the randomly placed images become laid out correctly.  I have the collection view inside a tablecellview

Comment: Is there some setting I need to reset when the cell is reused?